# Dating a diploma: "executed at" vs "done at" vs "given at" vs "signed at"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, legalese, translation

I am translating a typical French diploma into English. The translation will be certified, so I am trying to use the proper terms.

The diploma ends with a date:

[image]

which indicates when the diploma was made.

What is the best option amongst the following:

- ***Done*** at Paris, this 11th day of October, 2011
- ***Executed*** at Paris, this 11th day of October, 2011
- ***Given*** at Paris, this 11th day of October, 2011
- ***Signed*** at Paris, this 11th day of October, 2011

?

---

What I have seen so far:

Given:

[image]

Given in:

[image]

Given on:

[image]

Given at:

[image]

Comment: I'd use *Issued in Paris, on 11 October 2011*, or maybe just *Issued: 11 October 2011, Paris.* -- But don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 1):

Degrees and diplomas are usually **granted** (given) or **conferred**.

Possibilities are

> **Dated this day... in Paris** *("dated" is very simple and used on college diplomas in US)*
>   **Granted in Paris, this**...
>   **On this**... **day**... **in Paris**

How the date is referenced also depends on what the rest of the diplomas says.

**Done**, **executed**, and **given** are not used on a diploma certificate.
Legal documents are **issued** i.e. passports.